# Accessing a variable outside a c file

Tags: c, function, global-variables, header-files

I'm trying to do this code, and I split it up into `.c` files (lets say `file1.c` and `file2.c`) and `file1.h` file. I'm not allowed to change which parameters I can send to the function, so I need to find another way to "send"/access another variable. I tried to make the variable static in the header file `file1.h`, and include it in the `file2.c`. The function in `file1.c` look something like this:

```
int function(int *array, int a, int b){
        ...
        ...
    if(global_variable == 1){
        point = array[(a+b)/2];
    }else if(global_variable == 0){
        point = array[b];
    }
```

and in the `file2.c` I have a function something like this:

```
double function2(t_sort_funcp fun, const case_t c, int array_length, result_t *buf, t_generate_array_funcp g_array){
    int array[array_length];
    switch (c)
    {
    case first:
        global_variable = 1;
        g_array(array, array_length);
        return debugg(fun, array, array_length);
        break;
    case second:// Wors case is an inverted sorted array.
        global_variable = 0;
        g_array(array, array_length);
        return debugg(fun, array, array_length);
        break;
    case third:
        global_variable = 1;
        g_array(array, array_length);
        return debugg(fun, array, array_length);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the `file1.h` I have:

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <stdbool.h> // bool
static int global_variable;

#endif
```

as you can see, I'm trying to change the `global_variable` variable in `file2.c` and use it in `file1.c` but that does not work, the if-statement in `file1.c` always executes the code in the else-statement, even if I changed the variable to 1.
NOTE: `file2.c` always executes before `file1.c`

Comment: You should define `int global_variable;` as a global in one of the .c files, and change the .h file to be `extern int global_variable;`. Only place types and declarations in an .h file.

Comment: ... and macros. The header guard in the .h file does not prevent each .c file compilation including it. They are compiled independantly. The `static` keyword restricts the scope to that file. So in your code each .c file has its own instance of a variable called `global_variable` visible only in that compilation unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the opposite way

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <stdbool.h> // bool
extern int global_variable;

#endif
```

In one of the .c files

```
int global_variable;
```

Include the `.h` file in all files which require access to this variable.

`static` in global scope makes the variable only available in one compilation unit (file).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `extern` with a `cpp` conditional.

Below are samples files.

---

FILE: file1.h

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <stdbool.h> // bool

#ifdef FILE1_C
int global_variable;
#else
extern int global_variable;
#endif

#endif
```

---

FILE: file1.c

```
// I am file1.c
#define FILE1_C
#include "file1.h"
```

---

FILE: file2.c

```
// I am file2.c
#include "file1.h"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> definitely wrong way. Why this weird ifdef complication –
> 0___________

No, it's *not* the wrong way. I do this all the time. The idea is that you have *both* definitions in the same place/file. If you put the global in a `.c` file, it's harder to see if you change the type.

Here's a more expanded case:

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <stdbool.h> // bool

#ifdef FILE1_C
#define EXTRN_FILE1     /**/
#else
#define EXTRN_FILE1     extern
#endif

EXTRN_FILE1 int global_variable;
EXTRN_FILE1 double global_variable_2;

#ifdef FILE1_C
int global_variable_3 = 37;
#else
extern int global_variable_3;
#endif

#endif
```

And, we may want to put the globals in a different `.c` file. If we rename `FILE1_C` to (e.g.) `DEFINE_GLOBALS`, we can put `#define DEFINE_GLOBALS` in any `.c`. If we change our minds later, it's trivial to move the `#define` from (e.g.) `file1.c` to `file2.c`.

Comment: definitely wrong way. Why this weird ifdef complication? Declare in `.h` files, define in `.c` files

Comment: @0___________ Pardon me, but I've been using this construct in real code for decades. Perhaps the updated/expanded example will make it more clear.

Comment: Does it make it correct or good? The expanded code is IMO even worse.

Comment: *`The idea is that you have both definitions`* you have only one definition and declaration. In .h file you **declare** it and in the C file you define it. This .h file is a total mess.

Comment: @0___________ The idea is that you have both the definition and the declaration in one place in a single file. No need to rummage through a bunch of `.c` looking for the definition. You _can_ just do `int x;` in the `.h`. This is a common symbol (`nm` reports as type `C` in all `.o`). Then, it's _both_ declaration and definition at the same time (resolved by the linker). Fairly easy until `gcc` 12.0.0 where you need `-fcommon`. This construct has endured many code reviews. You're the first to ever complain. I guess we'll just have to disagree and leave it at that.

Comment: That idea is simple wrong. By the way, if you need to search "bunch of files" to find the definition, the project is a big mess. BTW in modern IDEs you can find the definition and the declaration in one mouse click (or maybe two).